# Does Explosive Hack deal damage only to enemies?

Tags: mass-effect-3

One of the rank 5 evolutions for the **Sabotage** power is called **Explosive Hack**. The description for this power reads:

> Synthetics explode when destroyed, dealing 490 points of damage across a 4 meter radius

Having my enemy explode after I've killed it with Nova could leave me in an even more vulnerable position than usual, as I often run around with a single bar of health in the middle of a fight repeating Charge-> Nova-> Charge.

Will the explosion from this skill cause damage to Shepard and her squadmates as well? I'm playing a Vanguard, so I'm rather up close and personal with most enemies, and I need to know if I'll have to take into account random explosions that will damage me when I'm killing things.

Comment: I severely doubt it but I haven't tested the asplosion yet. It'd be one of verrry few team damage abilities if it were though.

Comment: pretty sure there's no concept of team damage in ME3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I've tried that because I was wondering the same thing- as with the rest of ME3, there is no self-damage attached to it, only the enemy explodes.

Comment: A little unclear on your wording here re: "self-damage." So you're saying that yes, I and squaddies *will* be injured by the explosion as well? And just to doublecheck, this does damage to other enemies too?

Comment: No, nobody on your team is damaged by the explosion. And, yes, the other team's members do get damaged by the explosion, as long as they are close enough to the exploding enemy, they get damaged as it says that it deals damage across a radius around the exploded enemy.